# malloc mongoose webserver http post body and pass it to thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, malloc, mongoose-web-server

below is C snippet from mongoose webserver http event handler I am working on:

```
static void HttpEventHandler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *ev_data) {
if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST) {
    struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;
    if (mg_vcmp(&hm->method, "POST") == 0) {
        pthread_t thread_id;
        int rc;
        rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thr_func, /* Here I want hm body to be passed after its malloced */);
        if (rc) { /* could not create thread */
            fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc: %d\n", rc);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }//if POST
    mg_printf(nc, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    nc->flags |= MG_F_SEND_AND_CLOSE;
}
```

}

the http post message body, accessible as string using below syntax:

```
"%.*s", (int) hm->body.len,hm->body.p
```

I want code sample to malloc hm->body and pass it to the thread in snippet above, also it would be great to explain how to cast the passed void *. if its difficult then please malloc ev_data or hm.

Comment: so you want to pass a string as the parameter to `thr_func`?

Comment: yes, that's would be good enough since body content is json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd `malloc()` it as in:

```
    hm->body = malloc(sizeof *(hm->body));
    hm->body.p = "string"; 
    /* The above assigns a string literal. If you need to copy some
       user-defined string then you can instead do:
    hm->body = malloc(size); strcpy(hm->body.p, str); 
    where 'str' is the string you want copy and 'size' is the length of 'str'.
   */
    hm->body.len = strlen(hm->body);
```

and then pass it to:

```
rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thr_func, hm->body);
```

In `thr_func()` you would need to convert the argument to whatever the type of `hm->body` and then access it (because `void *` can't be dereferenced directly.). Something like:

```
void *thr_func(void *arg)
{
   struct mg_str *hm_body = arg;
   printf("str: %s, len: %zu\n", hm_body->p, hm_body->len);
   ...

   return NULL;
}
```

There's no need to cast anything to `void*`. The `pthread_create()` API expects a `void *` as the last argument and any data
pointer can be directly assigned to `void *`. The same applies to `struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;` statement as well.
It can be just: `struct http_message *hm = ev_data;`.

Depending how the "webserver" is implemented, you might need to take care of thread(s) completion as well.

P.S: If you show the "hm" structure, it'll be much easier to explain things.

Comment: hm structure available here (edited to point to line): https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/mongoose.h#L4053

Comment: can you please revise the answer, hm->body already filled with data after struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data; i think we need to malloc to new variable not hm->body. as for malloc size, can't we use hm->body.len?

Comment: If `hm->body` is already filled then you can skip the "malloc" parts and pass it directly to `pthread_create()` as shown.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh the takeaway is you can pass anything you want to a pthread function. It just "arrives" as a `void*` so you have to know which correct type to cast it back to before you can use it. If you want to pass a string, you'll have to cast it back to a `char*`. If you want to pass multiple parameters, you'll need to put them all in a `struct` and pass a pointer to that.

Comment: i am receiving compile error :(  error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘struct mg_str’)
    struct mg_str *bodyCopy = malloc(sizeof *(hm->body));

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh If that's the case then you need a copy. But I am not 100% sure what exactly you want to pass to the thread. If it's "hm->body" then: `struct mg_str *hm_body = malloc(sizeof *hm_body); hm_body->p = malloc(strlen(hm_body->len) + 1); strcpy(hm_body->p, hm->body.p); hm_body.len = hm->body.len;` will do the copy and you can pass `hm_body`. You'd also need to `free()` the allocations you've done after use. The error message appears to be a result of type mismatch. Please update your post with relevant code that produces that error.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Hmmm, sounds like you have bigger issues, perhaps with memory scope or thread synchronization?

Comment: still errors after applying latest code in comments:  warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    hm_body->p = malloc(strlen(hm_body->len) + 1);                                             error: request for member ‘len’ in something not a structure or union
    hm_body.len = hm->body.len;

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh Sorry, my previous comment had typos. It should be: `struct mg_str *hm_body = malloc(sizeof *hm_body); hm_body->p = malloc(strlen(hm->body.p) + 1); strcpy(hm_body->p, hm->body.p); hm_body->len = hm->body.len;`.

Comment: no errors but got warn and notice:  warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
    strcpy(hm_body->p, hm->body.p);
note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern char *strcpy (char *__restrict __dest, const char *__restrict __src)

Comment: Looks like the member `p` is `const` qualified. That's the reason for the warning. You can cast: `strcpy((char*)hm_body->p, hm->body.p);` (this would work because the memory returned by malloc is writable -- but this is really bordering along bad code). Alternatively, you can use a  *conditional variable*: 1) pass the original hm->body to the thread. 2) Take a copy of the "arg" in a local variable. 3) signal the HttpEventHandler that it's been copied (so that "hm" isn't destroyed before copy) and it can proceed.

Comment: i have strdup used somewhere else in the code, do you think strdup would fix strcpy warn? if yes, then please convert strcpy to strdup, thanks for all efforts.

Comment: casting (char*) eliminated the warning, please update the answer to reflect comments discussion, i will test the code and let you know, i hope you will keep follow up until mission success.

Comment: @JawadAlShaikh `strdup()` does the malloc()+strcpy() in one step - it's essentially the same. Or you can use a different struct: `struct my_msg_hdr { char *p; size_t len;}` and then copy the hm->body.p and hm->body.len to this: `struct my_msg_hdr *tmp = malloc(sizeof *tmp); tmp->p = strdup(hm->body.p); tmp->len = hm->body.len;` and then pass `tmp` your thread.

Comment: i am getting Assertion failed: pipes.empty () (src/lb.cpp:45)
Segmentation fault
this crash happen when the backend tcp listener that our pthread sends data to it is off. any ideas?